# (Adobe Illustrator) Can't change Align Stroke attribute in objects created with Shaper Tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, alignment, tools

Is it just buggy me or Adobe isn't thinking it's a necessary privilege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug.  It might be inconvenient but it's just that once you have made a Shaper Group object, it doesn't allow you to change the stroke alignment.  You could of course expand the shape made with the Shaper tool, then apply a different stroke alignment.

[image]

In fact, using the Shaper tool on shapes with strokes aligned to anything but centre, automatically switches the alignment to centre.

[image]

Comment: Nice illustrations! Thank you for confirming that it's not my end problem. By the way, can't find the option to release shaper tool created object, like ungroup it. Is there some magic trick?

Comment: @IgnatMiller 
 
If you have a shaper tool group, select it, then choose the shaper tool, click on the down arrow widget at the right edge of the selection to turn it into an up arrow, then click inside the object you want to remove, and drag and drop it outside the bounding box. See example here: http://imgur.com/a/UxsLl

Comment: thank you, this is barely an option to ungroup shaper tool groups, but I guess the only one at the moment

Comment: @IgnatMiller if you want boolean shaping that makes sense, look at every other drawing program not made by Adobe. It's only Adobe that gets it this wrong. Seemingly on purpose.